# Does extra outbound connection when tip is stale disable feeler connection?

Tags: p2p

I run a Bitcoin node for about 1.5 months and I notice that there is no feeler connection is made in 25 days, hence the IPs in the tried table does not grow.

I also notice in the debug.log during the same period of time, many potential stale tips are detected:

> 2019-02-20T13:26:59Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 2737 seconds ago)

Does extra outbound connection when tip is stale *disable* feeler connection?
If yes, is it normal to have stale tip for 20+ days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the netgroup of the feeler connection was not properly handled. 
Check further pull requests and fixes here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/15484